# Angular5 : @Input property that needs no value to equal "true"?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have this component:

```
export class TranslatedInputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dto:DTO;
  @Input() multi:boolean;
}
```

"multi" must be an attribute that doesn't need a parameter. Its presence should mean "true" and be used like follows if a multi-line input is expected:

```
<translated-input [dto]="newSymptom.title" multi></translated-input>
```

Right now, I have to bind a value:

```
<translated-input [dto]="newSymptom.title" [multi]="true"></translated-input>
```

What is the cleanest way to achieve having a property behave like an attribute directive?

Comment: If the constructor of your TranslatedInputComponent, is like constructor(private el: ElementRef), you can ask about (this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute("multi")!=null)

Comment: Thanks! Just found the following (copy/pasted) answer that leverages the @Input annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Material2](https://material.angular.io/) wrote the following method:

```
/** Coerces a data-bound value (typically a string) to a boolean. */
export function coerceBooleanProperty(value: any): boolean {
  return value != null && `${value}` !== 'false';
}
```

Use it as:

```
private _editMode: boolean;
@Input()
get editMode() { return this._editMode; }
set editMode(value: any) { this._editMode = coerceBooleanProperty(value); }
```

html:

```
editMode == true
<app-document editMode></app-document>

editMode == false
<app-document></app-document>
```

If you use Material2 you can simply import it

```
import {coerceBooleanProperty} from '@angular/cdk/coercion';
```